# How do I stop my htaccess set up from forcing an implicit redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

We have a link that looks like this:  domain2.com/directory/filename?v_search=?

and we want it to look like this:  domain1.com/directory/keyword-keyword-keyword

Our .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(-.*)?$ http://www.domain.com/directory/directory/directory/perl-program.html?v_search_string=$1 [NC,L]
```

When we go to the 2nd link, it forces an implicit redirect to the first link, without doing a rewrite.  Can you do a rewrite where the link is to another domain without getting an implicit redirect? How? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot serve content on domain1.com from domain2.com with mod_rewrite. You'd have to run a reverse proxy server on domain2.com to accomplish that.

Comment: We set up a ReverseProxy within the Apache Config and were able to get it to work. Thanks for the answer!